# cascade delete in android room database KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, delete-row, cascade

There are a bunch of questions like this in StackOverflow but most of that arent about room database, so I had to ask a new question.

I have an app that uses room database and that has near 4 tables and a big relationship between those tables, so for instance when I delete a user in user list fragment, that user delete(only userName and some personal info) but the user's TRANSACTIONS and LOANS hadn't been deleted.
Someone told me I have to use ***Cascade delete*** but I didn't find much info about it.

My User class model:

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_info")
data class UserInfo(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
var userId: Long =0L,
@ColumnInfo(name = "full_name")
var fullName:String?,
@ColumnInfo(name= "account_id")
var accountId: String?,
@ColumnInfo(name = "mobile_number")
var mobileNumber:String?,
@ColumnInfo(name = "phone_number")
var phoneNumber:String?,
@ColumnInfo(name = "date_of_creation")
var dateOfCreation:String?,
@ColumnInfo(name = "address")
var address:String?,
)
```

Transactions model class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "transactions")
data class Transactions(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "trans_id")
    var transId: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
    var userId: Long?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "create_date")
    var createDate: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bank_id")
    var bankId: Long?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    var description: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "increase")
    var increase: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "decrease")
    var decrease: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "loan_number")
    var loanNumber: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "total")
    var total: Long?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    var type: String?
)
```

User DAO:

```
 @Insert
suspend fun insert(ui: UserInfo): Long

@Update
suspend fun update(ui: UserInfo)

@Insert
suspend fun insertList(ui: MutableList<UserInfo>)

@Delete
suspend fun deleteUser(ui: UserInfo)

@Query("DELETE FROM user_info")
fun deleteAllUser()

@Query("SELECT user_info.user_id, user_info.full_name, transactions.total From user_info JOIN transactions ")
fun joinTable(): LiveData<List<UserAndMoney>>?

@Query("SELECT * from user_info WHERE user_id = :key")
fun get(key: Long): LiveData<UserInfo>?

@Query("SELECT * FROM user_info ORDER BY full_name DESC")
fun getAllUserInfo(): LiveData<List<UserInfo>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM user_info where full_name like '%' || :fullName || '%' ORDER BY full_name ASC")
fun searchUserName(fullName: String): LiveData<List<UserInfo>>
```

If It was not clear for you till now, let me makes it easy for you:

**I need cascade delete that delets every thing about user and a record.**

Comment: refer to [room-relationships](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CASCADE is an option of a Foreign Key constraint. So you would need to define Foreign Key constraints. You define Foreign Key constraints in Room via the @Entity annotation.

As an example, as it would appear that a Transactions is related to a UserInfo via `var userId: Long?,` (column name user_id) you could have :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "transactions",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = UserInfo::class,
            parentColumns = ["user_id"],
            childColumns = ["user_id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE, //<<<<<
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE // Optional
        )
    ]
)
data class Transactions(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "trans_id")
    var transId: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id", index = true) // <<<<< best to have an index on the column, not required
    var userId: Long?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "create_date")
    var createDate: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bank_id")
    var bankId: Long?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    var description: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "increase")
    var increase: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "decrease")
    var decrease: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "loan_number")
    var loanNumber: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "total")
    var total: Long?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    var type: String?
)
```

**Note**

The constraint enforces referential integrity, that is a transaction can not be inserted/updated if the user_id value is not a value that exists in the user_id column of the user_info table.

The CASCADE onUpdate will cascade a change to the user_id value in the user_info table to the respective transactions.

**Additional**

> Someone told me I have to use Cascade delete but I didn't find much info about it.

What you have been told is incorrect. You could replicate the functionality without `ON DELETE CASCADE` or without the Foreign Key constraint.

You could use

```
@Query("DELETE FROM transaction WHERE user_id=:userId")
fun cascadeDeletionsFromUser(userId: Long)
```

- noting that if the Foreign Key constraint exists in the transactions table but didn't have an onDelete action specified, then the `cascadeDeletionsFromUser` function would have to be run before the user_info row is deleted. Otherwise the user_info row could not be deleted as the FK constraint would inhibit the deletion.

If you had an **abstract class** rather than **interface** then you could have:-

```
@Query("DELETE FROM user_info WHERE user_id=:userId")
abstract fun deleteUserById(userId: Long)

@Query("DELETE FROM transactions WHERE user_id=:userId")
abstract fun cascadeDeletionsFromUser(userId: Long)

@Transaction
@Query("")
fun deleteUserWithCascade(userId: Long) {
    cascadeDeletionsFromUser(userId)
    deleteUserById(userId)
}
```

and use the deleteUserWithCascade function to delete the transactions and user in one go.

It is more convenient to use `ON DELETE CASCADE`, and especially so if you have multiple depths of relationships (when it gets a little more complex ascertaining children)